# Defining class in String for use in Gson

Tags: java, json, class, netbeans, gson

I am trying to use  `Gson` to instantiate a `User` object based on some `JSON`, defining the `class` in a `String`. However, it is not working.

The error `Netbeans`'s giving me is the following

[image]

Here's the code

```
    Class<?> myClass = Class.forName("User");

    Gson gson = new Gson();
    User user = gson.fromJson(json, myClass);
```

What is wrong with my approach?

Edit: The reason I am trying to do it like this, is because I **don't** know the type at compilation

Comment: You need to define `myClass` as `Class<User>`

Comment: The `?` wildcard literally means "Unknown". Not especially useful in this situation.

Comment: I updated the question. I **don't** know the type at compilation

Comment: To the person downvoting, please explain in a comment

Comment: `User user = gson.fromJson(json, myClass);` would suggest the type is known.

Comment: @Pixark Unfortunately, that's a problem. Java is strictly typed. In addition, if you're having to determine what a JSON object represents based on some string, it's a poor design (for this reason). All that said, if that's the case you're better off just deserializing to a `Map<String, Object>` and manually casting accordingly to get what you need.

Comment: @NickHolt The OP is trying to dynamically create objects based on a classname (presumably from part of the input).

Comment: @BrianRoach yes, but if the variable is declared as type `User` this implies the type is known at compile time.  I've explained this in my answer below :-)

Comment: @NickHolt It's not known at compile time if the classname is dynamic (i.e. from a string that is an external input)

Comment: @Pixark How are you determining what the JSON represents? You show a string literal which implies you *do* know what the class would be at compile time, which makes this very hard to answer.

Comment: @BrianRoach it is know at compile time if there's a variable declared of a specific type - the problem is related to generics and type inference as I've explained below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
User user = gson.fromJson(json, User.class);
```

Or if you don't know the type:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
Object obj = gson.fromJson(json, Class.forName("User"));
```

The error you're getting is to do with generics - the return type is being inferred from the type of the variable you're assigning the return value to.  This inferred type is is then being used with the class parameter.

```
public <T> T fromJson(String json, Class<T> classOfT)
```

Changing the type of the variable the return value is assigned to an `Object` means the class parameter will be type `Class<?>` and the compiler is happy.

Comment: I updated the question. I **don't** know the type at compilation

Answer (score 0):

```
Class<User> myClass = Class.forName("User");
```

or

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
User user = gson.fromJson(json, User.class);
```

Comment: The problem is I am getting the classname from JSON before-hand, so I do not know what type it is when compiling